# REST API call through marvel... Don't know syntax works with MD5

Tags: angularjs, rest, md5

Using Angular and UI router, if that's important. I'm calling an API through Marvel to bring in relevant comic book recommendations associated with particular characters (i.e. Luke Cage) in my view. I've found that Marvel uses MD5, which I have NO experience with. I'm used to making API calls through simple REST syntax:

https://jsbin.com/jakejaloyo/edit?js,output

through reading up I know I need to have my private API key and time stamp, but can't figure out the syntax to make it work.

Bonus question, why MD5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to concatenate the timestamp + privateKey + publicKey

- Ts - a timestamp (or other long string which can be changed on a request-by-request basis)
- Hash - a md5 digest of the ts parameter, your private key and your public key (eg md5 (ts + privateKey + publicKey)

Ex.:

```
var publickey = "YOUR-PUBLIC-KEY";
var privatekey = "YOUR-PRIVATE-KEY";
var ts = new Date().GetTime();
var stringToHash = ts + privatekey + publickey;
var hash = md5(stringToHash);

var url = "http://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters/1009215/comics?orderBy=focDate" + "&ts=" + ts + "&apikey=" + publickey + "&hash=" + hash;

var somenamefunction = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            ...
        })

    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just starting development, and dealing with MD5 security stuff was a bit overwhelming